# How to access a method of fragment from fragmentactivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a FragmentActivity which contains a viewpager. My  FragmentActivity has an menu in actionbar.I have a method in one fragment.I want to call that method ,onclick of menu in actionbar.
And in that fragment one listview is there.I want to change the text of menu item,onclick of each listitem .

Can anyone please help me how to do this.

Comment: You can store an instance of that `Fragment` in `FragmentActivity` and can access method

Comment: You can also use broadcasts to do so.

Comment: post some code snips for clear understanding , why you have the method inside fragment same can be achieved inside activity only by that it becomes simple to access and modify it.

Comment: YourAdapter adapter = ((YourAdapter)mViewPager.getAdapter());
MyFragment fragment = adapter.getFragment(index);
fragment.yourMethod(...) give an index of whichever fragment instance you want to access ... question is why do you have a method in fragment .... ?

Comment: Thank you codebased. I will try with the same.
and what about the 2nd part.I mean in my fragment one listview is there.I want to change the text of menu item,onclick of each listitem .and Menu item is there in FragmentActivity.How i can achieve this

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
((FragmentActivity)getActivity()).YourMethodName();
```

Comment: I think he's trying to do it the other way. ie: Access Fragment methods from FragmentActivity.

Comment: yeah Ruchira  i want to  access Fragment method from FragmentActivity

Answer (score 0):

```
ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment ();
fragment.<specific_Public_function_name>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find view pager current visible position by

```
int currentFragmentIndex = viewpager.getCurrentItem();
```

Now if you have store the view pager fragment in any container like list then you can get that fragment by get method. Like

```
Fragment myCurrentFragment = myList.get(currentFragmentIndex);
```

Please share your code for better help.